# How do I call a certain property/value object to use through out my data table after merging databases?

Tags: jquery, database, merge, datatable, callback

After merging the two databases, I need to populate the whole table with data from an `event.geometry.type` "Point" as well as the ones listed below.

Here is a portion of the code I've created so far:

```
        var data = $.merge(work, report);

        console.log(data);

        $.each(data, function (key, value) {

            data += '<tr>';
            data += '<td>' + value.representation.color + '</td>';
            data += '<td>' + value.key + '</td>';
            data += '<td>' + value.tooltip + '</td>';
            data += '<td>' + value.priority + '</td>';
            data += '</tr>';


        });

        $('#table').append(data);
        console.log(data);

    });
});
```

});

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What stops you from going even further with your code? What is your question that you wanted to ask?

Comment: Hi @Picard, thank you for welcoming me and being available! I am new to the tech field so I am still learning the language, please be patient while I try to formulate my questions/needs. I am using jquery and I called two API's and merged them using $.merge.  My table is rendering correctly with the values you see above but I also want to populate the table with only one geometry type "Point" and leave out the rest of the types. How do I call the geometry type "Point" into my table?